# What is the recommended Amplifier/Receiver (AVR) for my Surround Sound 5.1 Speakers Configuration?

Tags: amplifier, audio, speakers, receiver

Here are my speakers & subwoofer configurations, wondering if anyone can help me suggest a minimum AVR configuration I should go with:
[image: 5.1 Surround Sound Configuration]

I am looking at Harman/Kardon or Denon AVRs.
Little back story, I used to have JBL PB10 150W Subwoofer. Once it went bad, I replaced it with NHT CS-10 300W subwoofer then within a month my Harman Kardon AVR-500 went bad (it's making a slight humming/buzzing sound even when there is no audio play or with audio play, the buzzing is slight but still noticeable). Got it checked at the local electronics repair shop, and the shop said it has a burnt sign on the board and suspects it's the main processor which went bad may be due to overheating, and it's not cheap to replace it instead go with a new/used one. So wondering if adding a higher configuration subwoofer killed it? Thus wanted to make sure the next AVR I select should be compatible with the current speakers/subwoofer configurations I have.

If you think the subwoofer wouldn't have killed the AVR? I am easily finding that replacement HK AVR-500 in the used market for a very affordable price, so I will just stick with the same model.

One more thing, I noticed my Front Wall Speakers have 6ohm nominal impedance, and based on internet research I understand that Speakers must have more impedance than the set level of AVR impedance. But that AVR 500 lasted 15+ years with my Front Wall speakers.

Answer (score 1):

The NHT is a powered subwoofer that has its own amplifier. It cannot damage the main processor.
It will cause a hum/buzz sound if it is not fed through a shielded audio cable that might have worn out.

Answer (score 1):

You may have a defective Regulator but it Sounds like a leaky low ESR bulk cap inside AVR amp when you get hummmmm. Same within JBL woofer.

And likely it can be replaced with same or better and suspect all e-caps to be replaced or spend time testing each one with scope.

This is common to both channels.  Single channel issues are different. (Naturally)